# Does mashing the buttons make your guy get up faster?

Tags: wwe-2k16

In *WWE 2k16*, as with most games in the series, your character will often be knocked onto the ground, waiting for the opponent to approach to attack you and sometimes, whether through luck, bad AI, or taunting, you have time to get up before they attack you. In most wrestling games [hitting random buttons quickly will let you get up faster](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SmashingSurvival), but I honestly can't tell if it's also the case here.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from your own link:

> Smashing Survival is where in order to break free of an enemy's grip or shake loose from a trap you fell into, you have to either smash the buttons, frantically spin the analog stick, or a combo of both.
>
> It would be easier to list a Wrestling Game that didn't employ this to get out of holds, pins, and general stun.
>
> - WWE 2k15 and **WWE 2k16** are recent **aversions** where **it's been replaced** by a timing minigame.
>
> <sup>- **Fighting Games** in [TV Tropes' Smashing Survival](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SmashingSurvival)</sup>

Comment: That is the case for holds and pins, but there's no evident minigame for getting back up.